# Android Animating an ImageView for 2D Game Solution Issues

Tags: android

I'm trying to animate an ImageView for a 2D Game every time the screen is swiped and I've tried using a TranslateAnimation but there are no methods to update the initial values so everytime I move my character I would have to recreate the object although that won't work as I need to be able to use the hasStarted() method. Has anyone come across a similar problem and is able to advise a solution?

```
public synchronized void move() { 
    ani = new TranslateAnimation(width * oldLocX, width * locX, height * oldLocY, height * locY);
    ani.setDuration(3000);
    ani.setFillAfter(true);
    ani.setFillBefore(true);
    ani.setFillEnabled(true);
    oldLocY = locY;
    oldLocX = locX;
    if(!ani.hasStarted() || ani.hasEnded()) {
        bl.startAnimation(ani);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Animation currently running");
    }
}
```

I'm have to recreate the TranslateAnimation object everytime so It can never tell if its running or not..

Comment: posting a bit of your code would help us in giving you an insight or a solution.

Comment: Added some code, move() is called on swipe

Comment: If you're using Android API >= 11, I suggest you take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html) and [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html).